# Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, npm, sdk, expo, yarnpkg

I installed expo-cli initially with Yarn but it didn't work, so I just did the global install using npm. expo start doesn't work anymore after creating a new project using `expo init "site name" --name "name" -t blank --yarn`. After doing this I downloaded Android Studio and started a virtual device.

Here is my error message after I type `expo start`:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                         │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (4.3.4).                 │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 3.28.6                               │
│   Install expo-cli globally using the package manager of your choice;   │
│   for example: `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version      │
│                                                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Starting project at /home/user/"location"
Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
ConfigError: Cannot determine which native SDK version your project uses because the module `expo` is not installed. Please install it with `yarn add expo` and try again.
    at Object.getExpoSDKVersion (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config/src/Project.ts:23:9)
    at ensureConfigHasDefaultValues (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config/src/Config.ts:433:18)
    at fillAndReturnConfig (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config/src/Config.ts:112:10)
    at getConfig (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/config/src/Config.ts:149:10)
    at configureProjectAsync (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:287:25)
    at action (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:160:34)
    at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/start.ts:334:16
    at Command.<anonymous> (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:332:7)
```

expo diagnostics gives me this:

```
  Expo CLI 3.28.6 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 5.8 Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)
      Shell: 5.0.17 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 14.9.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.10 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.14.8 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/bin/npm
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119
    npmPackages:
      react: ^17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
      react-dom: ^17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 3.28.6
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Answer (score 0):

updated `npm` to the latest version -> `npm install -g npm@latest`

Uninstall expo -> `npm uninstall -g expo-cli --save`

Deleted the .expo folder, reinstalled expo can be worked

Comment: Thank you but that didn't fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

I was in the wrong directory altogether. Simple mistake, simple fix.